# Campaign Trackig : Field to set data in google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Campaign Tracking 
I have created a URL variable with **Component type as Query and Query key as source**. I have created  Tag that fires on all page in the TAG i have enable field to set option
**Fields to set**
               **Field Name          Value**
                **campaignSource     {{source_utm}}** were source_utm is URL variable that I have created.
TAG is getting fired and data is getting populated. In the debug mode following data is reflecting
**Filed to set        {campaignSource: '123'}**

URL is like this  : www.xyz.com/?source=123 
My Query were would I will be able to see the campaign data in  GA as i am not able see the data in campaign report. Also would like to know how long it take for campaign data to get populate in GA.This are the only steps  I have followed do I need to follow more other steps also .Also I would like to know how  can I access **Field to set** data in Google Analytics report. Please advice thanks

Comment: This isn't coding related and is therefore off topic, but you should be able to see campaign reports under Acquisition > Campaigns. From there you should be able to select the appropriate dimensions including campaign source. All GA data takes up to 24 hours to show up in standard reports, unless you are a Premium user.

Comment: thnx nyuen : Data is reflecting correctly